# Posting to ASP.NET URL keeps bringing me back to the same page via Python requests

Tags: python, asp.net, redirect, python-requests

I am using Python requests to ping a site that uses the ASP.NET framework. One of the URL's is giving me trouble and the response is the exact same page that I posted to, but the browser does not behave this way with the same URL - it refreshes with a new URL and all (but I do not think it is redirecting technically). What are some ways I can try to troubleshoot this? I would provide code and links but it is a secured website and requires authentication/subscription.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I resolved the issue with a less than ideal fix - I get as far as possible with the requests module and then I swap the cookies with a fresh selenium browser session to get the behavior I needed.